# Increment 16 byte char array in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have an array

```cpp
char msgID[16];
```

How do I increment this by 1? I read the high and low 8 bytes into 2 different `uint64_t` integers

```cpp
uint64_t high, low;
memcpy(&low,  msgID, sizeof(uint64_t));
memcpy(&high, msgID + sizeof(uint64_t) , sizeof(uint64_t));
```

If I do

```
low += 1;
```

How do I account for overflow?

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are trying to do your own 128-bit arithmetic?

Comment: Is the endianness the same for both `low` and `msgID`? If not, `memcpy` will not produce the result you think it will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple, actually:

```
if(++low == 0)
    ++high;
```

Comment: `high += !++low;`?

Answer (score 1):

Start with `msgID[15]` and increament. If it passes 255, it goes back to zero, increament the previous byte

```
for (int c = 15; c >= 0; c--)
    if (++msgID[c] != 0) 
            break;
```

Per suggested comment, do endian-test and increment accordingly

```
int endian_test = 1;
unsigned char buf[4];
memcpy(buf, &endian_test, 4);
//buf will be "1000" for little-endian, and "0001" for big-endian
int is_little_endian = buf[0];

if (is_little_endian)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++)
        if (++msgID[c] != 0)
            break;
}
else
{
    for (int c = 15; c >= 0; c--)
        if (++msgID[c] != 0)
            break;
}
```

Comment: This assumes big endian.

Comment: It's a good answer though. Maybe you could change the `for` loop depending on the endianness?  For example, `#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN ...`.

Comment: Note that msgID must be unsigned, otherwise the overflow is implementation defined ( http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.2.6.2.html ) and char (used by the OP) has implementation defined signedness.